# Html 5 components is not coming in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am working with android in eclipse .Using phonegap running the HTML5 components from asset folder.Html components is not coming in the  emulator using android 4.0.3 api.

Couldn't load vertex shader error message  is comming in the logcat.

my Activity class is given below.In that class I am using loadUrl method of the droidGap class.

I was trying to load an HTML5 page  which is actually a login page the blue screen coming only while trying to run the project.

```
package com.plugin.myapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        super.init();  

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html");
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/web/index.html",10000); 
    }
}
```

and the manifest.xml is given below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.plugin.myapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application       
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

LogCat  error message

```
10-25 10:30:06.649: D/dalvikvm(610): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
10-25 10:30:06.669: I/CordovaLog(610): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-25 10:30:06.669: I/CordovaLog(610): Found preference for useBrowserHistory
10-25 10:30:06.669: D/DroidGap(610): DroidGap.onCreate()
10-25 10:30:06.759: D/DroidGap(610): DroidGap.init()
10-25 10:30:06.839: D/DroidGap(610): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html)
10-25 10:30:06.839: D/DroidGap(610): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
10-25 10:30:06.839: D/PluginManager(610): init()
10-25 10:30:06.939: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(610): Ignore this event
10-25 10:30:06.999: D/gralloc_goldfish(610): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-25 10:30:07.209: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(610): Ignore this event
10-25 10:30:08.029: D/CordovaLog(610): Viewport argument value "device-width;initial-scale" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
10-25 10:30:08.029: D/CordovaLog(610): file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html: Line 8 : Viewport argument value "device-width;initial-scale" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
10-25 10:30:08.029: E/Web Console(610): Viewport argument value "device-width;initial-scale" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored. at file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html:8
10-25 10:30:08.029: D/CordovaLog(610): Viewport argument key "1.0;" not recognized and ignored.
10-25 10:30:08.039: D/CordovaLog(610): file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html: Line 8 : Viewport argument key "1.0;" not recognized and ignored.
10-25 10:30:08.039: E/Web Console(610): Viewport argument key "1.0;" not recognized and ignored. at file:///android_asset/www/tdc_tutorial.html:8
10-25 10:30:08.279: D/chromium(610): Unknown chromium error: -6
10-25 10:30:11.059: E/SQLiteLog(610): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-25 10:30:11.059: E/SQLiteLog(610): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): ERROR: 
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): Cause - unable to open database file
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
10-25 10:30:15.740: D/CordovaLog(610): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
10-25 10:30:15.740: D/CordovaLog(610): file:///android_asset/www/TestClient.lzx.js?: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
10-25 10:30:15.749: E/Web Console(610): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/TestClient.lzx.js?:1
10-25 10:30:26.050: D/dalvikvm(610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 5% free 8423K/8839K, paused 82ms+5ms, total 117ms
10-25 10:37:41.439: D/dalvikvm(610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 426K, 6% free 8431K/8967K, paused 75ms+4ms, total 119ms
10-25 10:44:16.459: D/dalvikvm(610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 398K, 6% free 8456K/8967K, paused 76ms+5ms, total 120ms
```

can any body help me to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

According to these lines of your log:

```
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): ERROR: 
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): Cause - unable to open database file
10-25 10:30:11.059: D/WebKit(610): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
10-25 10:30:15.740: D/CordovaLog(610): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
10-25 10:30:15.740: D/CordovaLog(610): file:///android_asset/www/TestClient.lzx.js?: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
10-25 10:30:15.749: E/Web Console(610): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/TestClient.lzx.js?:1
```

Your code is trying to read some sql files which it is unable to do. You might wanna check this out

Comment: If you are not, then webkit is. See the filepath in the log and check if the file is present